# Error al sumar top position

Tags: javascript

```js
var b = document.getElementById("m");
  
function f(){
 b.style.top += "10px";
} 
setInterval(f,1000);
```

```css
#m {
  
  border-radius: 360px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <center>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/5uCVACi.png" id="m"/>
  </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Quiero que cada segundo, baje 10px más pero no es así y solo baja 1 vez, por que?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problemas:

El primer problema es que `b.style.top` inicialmente es igual a `""` (una cadena vacía). El `top` se lo has indicado a través de la regla `CSS` `#m`

Demo:

```js
var b = document.getElementById("m");
console.log(b.style.top === '');
```

```css
#m {
  border-radius: 360px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/5uCVACi.png" id="m"/>
```

El segundo problema es que al hacer `b.style.top += "10px";`, no estas sumando, sino concatenando.

Demo:

```js
var b = document.getElementById("m");
console.log('b.style.top === "" ? ', b.style.top === '');
console.log(b.style.top += '10px');
console.log(b.style.top += '10px');

console.log('Como "10px10px" no es un valor válido, es descartada la parte inválida');
console.log(b.style.top);

// Ejemplo 2
console.log('Otro ejemplo');
console.log(b.style.top = '22px');
console.log(b.style.top += '11px');
console.log(b.style.top);
```

```css
#m {
  
  border-radius: 360px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/5uCVACi.png" id="m"/>
```

### Solución:

Necesitamos es obtener el `top` de `m`. Como esta seteado a través de una clase entonces podemos usar una de las siguientes opciones:

- [`Element.offsetTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop)

  > La propiedad de sólo lectura HTMLElement.offsetTop retorna la distancia del elemento actual respecto al borde superior del nodo offsetParent.

Ejemplo:

```js
var b = document.getElementById("m");

function f() {
  b.style.top = (b.offsetTop + 10) + "px";
  console.log(b.style.top);
}
setInterval(f, 1000);
```

```css
#m {
  border-radius: 360px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/5uCVACi.png" id="m" />
</center>
```

- [`Window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

  > Devuelve el estilo computado del elemento. Los estilos computados representan los valores finales de las propiedades CSS del elemento.

  Si usamos esta `API`, vamos a necesitar obtener la parte númerica en la propiedad `top`. Para esto, la forma más simple es usar [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseFloat) (*en este caso podríamos usar `parseInt`, pero como `top` acepta decimales, `parseFloat` es una solución más general*)

Ejemplo:

```js
var b = document.getElementById("m");

function f() {
  var top = window.getComputedStyle(m, null).top;
  b.style.top = (parseFloat(top) + 10) + "px";
  console.log(b.style.top);
}
setInterval(f, 1000);
```

```css
#m {
  border-radius: 360px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/5uCVACi.png" id="m" />
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo baja 1 vez porque al cambiar el valor del estilo `top`, se le está sumando cada vez la cadena de texto `"10px"`, en vez del valor numérico 10.

Para solucionarlo se puede crear una variable contador, a la cual se le suma 10 cada vez que la función se ejecuta. Luego se asigna al estilo `top` la variable `contador` más el texto `"px"`.

Se debe cambiar:

```
var b = document.getElementById("m");

function f(){
 b.style.top += "10px";
} 
setInterval(f,1000);
```

por:

```
var b = document.getElementById("m");
var contador = 4;
function f(){
    contador += 10;
    b.style.top = contador + "px";
}
setInterval(f,1000);
```

**Código funcionando:**

```js
var b = document.getElementById("m");
var contador = 4;
function f(){
    contador += 10;
    b.style.top = contador + "px";
}
setInterval(f,1000);
```

```css
#m {
  
  border-radius: 360px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <center>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/5uCVACi.png" id="m"/>
  </center>
    </body>
</html>
```